# Rotation of 3 spin-1/2 particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

How would I rotate 3 spin-1/2 particles in, say, a triangular configuration in the xy-plane  (rotating about z-axis)? Griffiths does not introduce this sort of system. Of course, I see that 3 successive rotations of $\phi = 2\pi/3$ should return me back to the initial configuration, but I don't understand how to apply a rotation operator.

Comment: Why is the configuration of the particles in space relevant? Or, if what we're rotating is the configuration as a whole, why is the spin of the individual particles relevant?

Comment: @ACuriousMind well, first, I include a configuration so we know what sort of rotation(s) will produce the initial system. Second, I imagine the spins are relevant because we have a J in the exponential-form of the rotational operator.